# Project directory structure with 3rd party components

Tags: delphi, components, build-automation, project-structuring

I have to maintain old software written in Delphi. The source tree is a real mess. I'm trying to do 2 things: to make clean directory structure and to set up automated build process.

Right now i have produced following directory tree

```
  \Project
     \build\output   
     \dist\release
     \dist\debug
     \doc
     \env
     \res
     \src
```

`\src` directory contains `*.pas` and `*.dfm` files and `project.dpr`. Various resources (icons, images and fonts) are reside in `\res` directory. `\env` is used to create various environments for debugging purposes. IDE was setted up to build project.exe into this dir.
Build scripts are stored in `build` folder. These scripts produce product distribution (with and without debug information in exe) in `dist\release` and `dist\debug` folders with help of `dcc32.exe`. `build\output` is used to save dcu files during build process inside IDE or inside build script.

There is a little flaw in my approach. I can not start with fresh computer, checkout code from my repo, start building script and receive ready to use disitribution of the project. I need to open IDE first, install required components (e.g. `RXLib` and `MemoEx`), set up library paths and so on. Only after that steps i can run my building scripts.

It was not a big problem until last week. I've modified 3rd party component in order to fix a bug (this component isn't maintained anymore :-(), so i have to add code of this component to the structure of my project. At this point if i will checkout from the repo I need to check if there were changes in code of 3rd party libs. If code of libs was changed I need to recompile components and reinstall them.

Questions

1. Is there any way to reinstall components in Delphi 7 from command line? Is there any way to do it without hardcoding installation path of D7?
2. How would you store code of third part components in project tree?
3. Where should i place `bpl` and `dcu` which will be produced during build of components. Should i place them at `Project\build\output`? Or it will be better to place output to another location (do not override Delphi settings), but change Library path in project configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Noticed the Install from command line Request part of the question.

You can't really install from the command line but it would be easy to build something
that did that.    You can compile the packages using DCC32.EXE.

The installation of components is controlled by registry entries.  The location in the registry is different for each version of Delphi, but it does follow the same basic pattern.
Examples:

Delphi 2007
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Known Packages`
Delphi XE
'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\Known Packages'

We update this using FinalBuilder, after we have build all the 3rd party components.
It makes it easier to keep each developer in sync.

As for directory structure, I think about version control up front and do the following.

Root Directory...

```
C:\dev\trunk\
```

This allows me to create branches in an easy format.

```
C:\dev\branch1\
```

From there I do the following:

I use a common directory for \Bin and \DCU since I do a lot of package development
many of which need to be loaded at design time.    This prevents having to add many
directories to the system path to keep Delphi happy.

```
\output\DelphiXE\Bin
\output\DelphiXE\Dcu
```

This can be enhanced if need to be like this:

```
\output\DelphiXE\Release\Bin
\output\DelphiXE\Release\Dcu
\output\DelphiXE\Debug\Bin
\output\DelphiXE\Debug\Dcu
```

The for each project, I do this, although often I place more than one project in the same
directory if the rely on the majority of the same code.

```
\project\ (DPR/DPK Here)
\project\source (if the project is small, if not I break it out further)
\project\forms\
\project\classes\
\project\datamodules\
\project\resources\
\project\install\ (Install Scripts)
etc...
```

The finally for components and code common to different projects.

```
\Commonlib\ (Directory for my code that common among projects)
\Components\3rdPartyName\
\Components\3rdPartyName2\
\Components\3rdPartyName3\
```

I do it this way so I know every thing made up my version X of my application by just using the version control revision number.

To top this off I create an environment variable for

C:\DEV\TRUNK\

Then I use the environment variable in the system library path.
Like this:

```
%MYCODE%components\3rdParty1;%MYCODE%components\3rdParty2\
```

Then if I have to switch branches I can change the environment variable relaunch Delphi and everything using that version of the code base.

Comment: Nice information. This is the kind of tool I keep meaning to build. Then I go check out the JVCL installer which started out like that, and I think, maybe I'll just modify the JVCL installer.

Answer (score 6):

1. You just have to compile the package with the delphi commandline compiler. If the Delphi bin path is in your `PATH` you don't have to hard code the installtion path. If your build system is able to read from the registry you get the path e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\RootDir` (Delphi 2009 in this case).
2. I would add another branch `components` with subbranches for every package. Do not mix them with your projects.
3. From my experience the best practive is to keep them in the delphi destination (where depends on the delphi version).

Comment: If you recommend to add `components` as submodules (subrepos in terms of mercurial) then it would be better to store `dcu` and `bpl` somewhere inside of their repos. Isn't it? In other case sometime it will screw up build process for another app which use the same component but another version.

Comment: I mean what if each `component` will reside in `component\src` and build tool will compile `dcu` and `bpl` to `component\build`. These dcu and bpl files will be used to install component into IDE (design-time).

In the meantime my `project.dof` will be edited to use Library path `..\components\component\src` . During build of the project tool will lookup into this directory and build component's units to dcu and store them at `project\build\output`.

Comment: @Konstantin Mikhaylov, your view on "install component" might be a bit off. Components are installed as packages (DCP's), and there's only ONE list of installed packages, the list is not "per project". Components don't get installed into the IDE when you open a project, and they're not changed when you close the project and open an other one. In fact the Delphi IDE allows you to open multiple projects at once! That's why in my answer I say "no project owns 3rd party components", so I don't recommend putting them under version control in the same directory with the actual project itself [...]

Comment: @Konstantin Mikhaylov, [...] If 3rd party components aren't part of the project, you don't have the problem of matching 3rd party components to the onces used in the project. Actually you do, but it can't be solved as part of the project. Once that's out of the way, you might want to reconsider your option to store DCU and BPL files in Mercurial. I'm also using Mercurial, and it's grate; But it doesn't like binary files and DCU, BPL and EXE are all binary files. I don't store them in VCS. As part of any release I'm always doing "build all" so the DCU's have no value.

Answer (score 3):

1: Yes and no, you can design *your own* components to be installed from the command line (where "from the command line" means install them programatically, if you really want command line, you might need to write the tool). 3rd party components usually come with an installer that does more then install and register the components themselves. Theoretically you can automate everything the installer does and essentially repackage the component for your own use, but you might run into legal barriers doing this.

2: 3rd party components aren't tied to a project. Storing those files in the project directory is not a good idea. What happens when you reuse the same components in an other project? Do you copy all source files to the new project? For my own work I've got all 3rd party components installed into one folder, separate from any project's directory, and I keep that folder under version control.

3: Using a separate output directory for each project is a good idea, it makes using conditional compilation much easier. I'd suggest separate output directories for Debug and Release. About 3rd party BPL's, they're also not part of the project because no single project "owns them".

Comment: I doubt there are any Legal Barrier, for installing components in an automated way.   We use FinalBuilder to rebuild everything including 3rd party components.   Then we wrote a script to install them into Delphi.  The biggest reason is keep versions of 3rd party components in sync amoung 10 different developers is now really easy...  SVN UPDATE.  Run the FinalBuilder Script.